# Can't use Eloquent inside Slim Middleware

Tags: php, eloquent, slim

I'm using slim framework and i'm just trying to check a value from database inside my middleware, but i got an error :

```
Message: Call to a member function connection() on null
```

This is my middleware code :

```
->add(function ($request, $response, $next) {

    $user = App\User::find($_SESSION['userid']);

    if($user->permission == 1  ){
        $response = $next($request, $response);
    }else{
        return $response->withRedirect('noPermission');
    }

    return $response;
});
```

I'm adding this to my group

This is how i initialize the eloquent in dependencies.php file :

```
  $container['db'] = function ($container) {
    $capsule = new \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
    $capsule->addConnection($container['settings']['db']);
    $capsule->setAsGlobal();
    $capsule->bootEloquent();
    return $capsule;
  };
```

It's maybe the code execute before establishing a db connection !?

Thanks for help

**Note: i can use eloquent inside my routes**

Comment: Where do you initialize eloquent?

Comment: in the dependencies.php file

Comment: Can we see that file?

Comment: i added the code in the question description

Comment: thanks guys i solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just solved this by editing the dependicies file like this :

```
    $capsule = new \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
$capsule->addConnection($container['settings']['db']);
$capsule->setAsGlobal();
$capsule->bootEloquent();
$container['db'] = function ($container) {
    global $capsule;
    return $capsule;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The container may not have initialized the capsule of eloquent yet. You can do this by your self.

```
$container->get('db');
```

Do this after you added it to the container.

Answer (score -1):

Try this inside middleware, but you have to add middleware to the app first.

$this->container->db